# Find equation for $f(x)=a^{-x}$ graph from points given?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[An example of the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zr674.png)

I want to find the equation for this graph with the known point of (120,5)and approximate points of (300,2) (225,2.5) and (150,4).

Can I do this or do i need more information?

Comment: What you tried? What do you think, you need more points or not?

Comment: I tried simultaneous equations at first but then wondered if it would even work, and I do have more points, I'll add those to the question.

Comment: Do you want a curve $f(x) = a^{-x}$ on which those points lie exactly? This is not possible. Or do you want such a curve where those points are approximately on the curve (e.g. a regression type problem)?

Comment: The curve needs to go through the point (120,5) but all other points are just approximations.

Answer (score 1):

You only need a single point to specify the parameter $a$, if $f(x) = a^{-x}$. However, the other points will not lie on this curve.

If you have that $f(x) = a^{-x}$ and $(x, f(x)) = (120,5)$, then
$$a^{-120} = 5 $$
and hence by taking the natural logarithm on both sides we get
$$\ln \left( a^{-120}\right) =  -120\ln a = \ln 5$$
and hence
$$\ln a  = -\frac{\ln 5}{120}.$$
Applying the exponential function on both sides we get
$$a = e^{-\frac{\ln 5}{120}} = \left(e^{\ln 5}\right)^{-1/120} = 5^{-1/120}.$$

Therefore your function is $f(x) = \left(5^{-1/120}\right)^{-x}.$ However, the other points are not at all close, e.g. 
$$f(300) = 25\sqrt{5} \approx 55.9$$
which is not at all close to $2$. Therefore you need another model than $f(x) = a^{-x}.$

Answer (score 0):

First point can evaluate $a$. But third point would not be on the curve.. A least squares approximation can be found for next two points, would not be a good enough fit. If you confine to the exponential you gave, it is all that can be done.

Choosing a circular arc would fit the three points exactly.